# Connect polygons with gap without dissolve intersected polygons in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, aggregate

I want to close gaps between polygons that are not intersecting and without a barrier in between (like streets).
Its possible by "Aggregate Polygons", but this tool is dissovling all intersecting polygons and the one within a distance.

Is it possible to aggregate or connect neighboring polygons (or closing the gaps between) within 1 m and in the same time without dissolving directly adjacent ones?

It is important that edges remain at not relevant polygons.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the snap tools in the toolboxes of ArcGIS or QGIS?  The 1m would be your tolerance setting.

Comment: Should the buildings move, or expand to fill the gaps?

Comment: Expand, not relevant edges should remain!

Comment: Snap can solve it somehow. But small structures within a polygon get changed as well. But as a first result, I can work with it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try [Integrate](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/integrate.htm), but backup your data first because the tool will modify it.

> Analyzes the coordinate locations of feature vertices among features
> in one or more feature classes. Those that fall within a specified
> distance of one another are assumed to represent the same location and
> are assigned a common coordinate value

Then Dissolve if you want to dissolve the borders.

Comment: It would connect polygons indeed, but there is no chance to add a barrier feature. So polygons would get connected without any consideration of lines.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing your data?

Comment: Additionally, if I set a threshold of 50 cm in the Intregate Tool, it still connects nodes, which have a distance of 1,20 m, and i dont know why.